# Jointjs online original demo does not work in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, jointjs

I am trying to use joints for simple diagramming tasks.

Recently I noticed my application is broken in IE 11. 
After a short investigation it turned out that even the original [online demo](http://jointjs.com/demos/erd) is broken in IE 11. (missing connecting relationship lines, see attached picture)
Actually the error in my app is more serious, even shapes do not rendered.
*All works perfectly in latest Chrome and FF.*

*What makes me completely helpless is the complete lack of javascript errors.*

More details:

- Using Win 7 64 bit
- Using IE 11.0.9600.17501
- [Link to the online demo](http://jointjs.com/demos/erd)

Any workaround, or missing I something?
Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you have the same problem on your project try to download jquery 2.03 version. have a look and check that you have the same jquery version that jointjs plugin.

http://jointjs.com/download

If you are using multiple versions of jquery, remember to use jQuery.noConflict()